# Can capacitors be used to work as a mosfet?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, capacitor

I'm a beginner to electronics and I'm trying to work out how to make a MOSFET circuit using purely capacitors, I understand that a MOSFET can be replicated using capacitors - however the unique nature of the control gate makes me feel it`s not possible?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's certainly a new idea, at least to me - what source do you have?

Comment: Capacitors are not semiconductors. MOSFETs are.

Comment: You can make a kind-of thyristor using capacitors (hint: it's called a spark gap with a central electrode).

Comment: I think maybe you meant to say that a capacitor can be replicated using a MOSFET. The gate of the MOSFET is basically a small capacitor.  However, with a 2 terminal capacitor you can't replicate a 3 terminal MOSFET.

Answer (score 8):

The gate of a MOSFET has significant capacitance, but that certainly isn't the key to how a MOSFET works. You need a semiconductor channel that can be turned on and off by displacing charge within the crystal lattice.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds akin to modeling a BJT transistor with diodes.  It may work well enough when measuring the characteristics between any pair of two pins while leaving the third pin unconnected (assuming an enhancement mode MOSFET that is off by default).

But it doesn't capture the essence of what makes a transistor a transistor: using one pin to control what happens between the two other pins.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. A key element of a MOSFET is the [field effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_effect_(semiconductor)), a semiconductor behavior in which an electric field modifies the conductivity of a channel. That doesn't happen in capacitors, and requires a semiconductor to achieve. Furthermore, even if your capacitor did have some semblance of field effect where one electrode's field affects the conductivity on the other one, your capacitor likely isn't wired with three terminals anyway.

However, going in the other direction, MOSFETs do have capacitance between their terminals, and can be used as capacitors in some applications. It's common to use so-called MOSCAPs in RF systems since they're easy to fabricate on-chip. It's worth noting that these MOSFET based capacitors often have a capacitance varying substantially with the applied voltage due to the semiconductor's physical behaviors.

Comment: What if you could monitor the capacitor charge, then make a way at select charge levels, to trigger current into another system?

Comment: @starboy You could do that in principle, but it wouldn't be an inherent part of the capacitor. Rather, it would be a whole second circuit - in the simplest case, just a MOSFET that "monitors" the capacitor voltage by having the same voltage applied to its real MOSFET gate following the same square-law physics of the MOSFET. Or, it would be a whole purpose-designed circuit with selected charge levels, involving multiple comparators (each of which is comprised of multiple MOSFETs)

Comment: yeah so my thinking was to use multiple capacitors in a circuit to replicate the mosfet behaviour? but I think it would need a mosfet regardless as you say.

Comment: @starboy I'm not sure what those multiple capacitors would even net you in that kind of setup. I can't really think of a circuit topology that matches the description you're saying, and multiple capacitors just lets you do voltage/current division in series/parallel, without giving you any nonlinear, active, amplifying, or controlling behavior.